# Does anyone use non-sober topological spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology, soft-question, examples

Recall that a [sober space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space) is a topological space such that every irreducible closed subset is the closure of exactly one point.

Is there any area of mathematics outside of general topology where non-sober spaces are objects of interest?

I can't think of any cases at least in algebraic topology where such a space can't be replaced by a homotopy-equivalent sober space.  All manifolds are sober, and all schemes are sober, so it seems like as far as geometry goes, all spaces are also sober.

I suspect that if non-sober spaces show up, it might be in some special cases in infinite-dimensional functional analysis, but that's just a guess.

PS - Community Wiki It!

PPS - The question is motivated by the comment on this page in Johnstone's Elephant:

[image: Quoted page of Johnstone]

Comment: I’m posting as a comment, since this is a might-be-example, rather than an example, but I believe that it’s not known whether the Ziegler spectrum of a ring is always sober.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Wikipedia says they frequently fail to be T0, and sober implies T0.  Ergo, your example is indeed an example.

Comment: Hmm, Wikipedia also says that it’s not known whether they’re always sober, so this line of argument may be proving more about Wikipedia than about Ziegler spectra.

Comment: The space of irreducible representations of a C*-algebra with its usual topology is not T0 in general.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Perhaps  the Wikipedia entry meant T1?

Comment: Can you repeat the comment or give the page number since not everyone gets your page as part of the free Google preview.

Comment: Isn't the usual Zarisski topology on $P^2$ non-sober?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yeah, as a classical variety, but it's in a non-essential way.  The schematic Zariski topology makes it correct.

Comment: One could argue the max-spec of a commutative ring is an interesting non sober space although it can be soberfied by adding generic points. So I am thinking of things like Hartshorne chapter I where generic points are missing.

Comment: Sorry I was writing this as @DimaPasechnik wrote

Comment: Ah, it seems that there are two slightly different definitions of “sober” out there, which agree for $T_0$ spaces. The one the model theorists seem to like only requires a closed irreducible set to be the closure of a point (not necessarily unique).

Comment: Couldn’t it be argued that it’s cheating a bit to reject a “classical” (just closed points) variety because the “correct” scheme-theoretic version is sober? Can’t you “sober up” any ($T_0$, maybe) topological space by adding generic points? And certainly there are still people who “use” classical varieties, including the Zariski topology on them, without thinking scheme-theoretically?

Comment: @JeremyRickard I was thinking about it, and I'm really looking for spaces equipped with algebraic structure (like a TVS) that isn't compatible with soberification.

Comment: “Soberfied”? “Soberification”? **Clearly** the terminology should derive from “sober up”!

Comment: @HarryGindi - well, I am not full-time algebraic geometer and I happen to use the usual Zariski topology. I won't be surprised if an extra algebraic or analytic structure attached to the variety will provide it a permanent supply of liquor, preventing detoxification...

Comment: soberification is akin to compactification; you can compactify spaces under pretty mild assumptions, but this does not meant that non-compact spaces play no role in mathematics outside of topology...

Comment: For what it's worth, most dictionaries seem to list "soberize" but not "soberify".

Comment: Alexandroff topology of a poset is sober only if the poset has acc, so one can say that those who work with non-acc posets work with non-sober T$_0$ spaces...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think your answer is optimal. Consider making it an answer instead of a comment, so that this question doesn't linger on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @DavidWhite, I am turning my comment into an answer.

One class of very naturally appearing non-sober spaces is that of Alexandroff topologies on infinite posets. An irreducible closed subset in such a topology for a poset is precisely a directed downset, i. e. an ideal, so the Alexandroff topology of a poset $P$ is sober iff every ideal of $P$ is principal. In particular, $P$ cannot contain infinite ascending chain (this is also sufficient under some choice principle I am not sure about).

Thus the Alexandroff topology of any poset possessing infinite ascending chains is non-sober.

Comment: Great! Strongly support not leaving old questions unanswered forever.